# Spark - Local mode Vs Yarn mode

Tags: apache-spark

I am aware of internals and also went through https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls.

I come across the following

```
local[*]    Run Spark locally with as many worker threads as logical cores on your machine.
```

I am also aware of yarn cluster and client mode. Does the local means spark distribution installed locally contrary to yarn mode ( which is installed in cluster)
And also, when I submit the following command,it seems it is submitted to the cluster as it is working fine and I didnt have a local setup. So, I am presuming it is submitted to the cluster.

So, what is the difference here ?

```
spark-submit --master local[*]  word-count.py
```

Is it same as the following command ( as there is a "local" setup, here ) ?

```
spark-submit --master yarn word-count.py
```

***# Update 1***

I noticed one difference . With Yarn mode, the application details are displayed in Yarn applications page. I didnt see this in local mode.

I am wondering, where does it exactly the application deployed in "Local mode" is getting executed. I dont have a local setup of the cluster

Is the localmode by-passing the yarn cluster but still getting executed in the spark cluster ?

Comment: if you have a cluster of 5 machines (1 master and 4 core). `YARN` will help you run on all 5 machines. `local` will only help you run on a `single machine` ( master machine .. from where you submit) .

Comment: in "local mode" where does it exactly runs ? In cluster or in driver machine ?

Comment: @Nag Just look it like this: *local* has no cluster involved (there's no cluster manager, it's all running in the same JVM process). Cluster mode (standalone, yarn, kubernetes, etc.) coordinate executions across computers. Although you can run in cluster mode on the same local computer (as you're doing with yarn), the coordination of work and the processes are completely different from the local mode.

Comment: Can I put this way, as i am connecting to VM (where spark is installed) and local machine didnt have spark setup , when i submit the program with _local_ mode , it is submitted to the VM. The VM is executing the job in local mode as in everything in the same JVM Process _without_ using yarn .

Comment: You are submitting `spark-submit --master local[*]` inside the VM only right? I guess you are confused with the term `local` .

Comment: `local` refers to the machine/vm on which you are running `spark-submit` . 
If you run this in VM , then VM is the local for spark. Likewise, if you submit in your laptop's own terminal, then your laptop is the local for spark.